# Jquery delete selectable item text

Tags: jquery, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a code that works but there is a little bug there. I have selectable menu when I select items it shows which items are selected. When I press delete button it deletes the selected items and text but when I click again to some item it shows deleted items name in selected items menu. How can I avoid this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/dx5c04p5/1/

```
<style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em;}
  span{ text-decoration: underline; background-color:#b6be98; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: white; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #91b547; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  </style>
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
      stop: function() {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
          result.append( " " + ( $(this).text()));
        });
      }

    });

    $("#delete").click(function(){
        $('#selectable .ui-selected').hide();   
        $( "#select-result" ).empty();
    });
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem.  Looks good to me.

Comment: I second that, all works fine for me too.

Comment: first select for example 2 item. There will be shown : Selected Items:  Item 1 Item 2. When you delete them it will be empty. then select another item now there will be shown : Selected Items:  Item 1 Item 2 Item 3, name deleted items are shown

Comment: why im the only one that doesn't work maybe there is something wrong on my pc.